# Spring Boot GraalVM com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Proxy class defined by interfaces

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to compile my spring boot application with graalvm into native image using gradle plugin. After compilation and when I try to run the application using the generated file, I am getting the following error:

```
com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Proxy class defined by interfaces [interface org.hibernate.query.hql.spi.SqmQueryImplementor, interface org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmInterpretationsKey$InterpretationsKeySource, interface org.hibernate.query.spi.DomainQueryExecutionContext, interface org.hibernate.query.SelectionQuery, interface org.hibernate.query.CommonQueryContract] not found. Generating proxy classes at runtime is not supported. Proxy classes need to be defined at image build time by specifying the list of interfaces that they implement. To define proxy classes use -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=<comma-separated-config-files> and -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=<comma-separated-config-resources> options.
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:92) ~[na:na]
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.proxy.DynamicProxySupport.getProxyClass(DynamicProxySupport.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:47) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:na]
    at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1034) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:316) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy73.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:297) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:242) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:234) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:223) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy58.findByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at iee.ihu.gr.pricemonitoringbackend.DevInitializer.run(PriceApplicationInitializers.kt:51) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:3.1.2]
    at iee.ihu.gr.pricemonitoringbackend.PriceMonitoringBackendApplicationKt.main(PriceMonitoringBackendApplication.kt:17) ~[PriceMonitoringBackend:na]
```

The error occurs in my application initialiazer that I am using to insert some test data into the database.
I am using spring started jpa with hibernate.

The error is caused by this line

```
val testUser = customerRepository.findByEmail("test@email.com").get()
```

Which is call to spring jpa repository.

```
  interface CustomerRepository : JpaRepository<Customer,Long>{
    
        fun findByEmail(email: String) : Optional<Customer>
    
    }
```

My gradle build files looks like this :

```
    plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.23"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.22"
}

group = "x.y.z"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["testcontainersVersion"] = "1.17.6"

dependencies {
    //spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose")
    implementation("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")


    //kotlin
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0")

    //other
    implementation("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0")

    //test
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:mysql")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core-jvm:5.5.5")
    implementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.1.2")

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${property("testcontainersVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I resolve it so:

1. remove your target folder
2. run this command on the root path of your project:

> ./mvnw spring-boot:run

3. I copy all files (proxy-config.json, reflect-config.json, ...)  was generated by the last command to a directory *src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/group/artefact*